# Meteor.js, HTTP.call to be waited redirect other pages

Tags: meteor

HTTP.get 'http://url', (err, rslt) ->

I need to grab other webpage with HTTP.call methods, but the page is redirected after 5seconds the methods called.

So now I used phantomjs to wait 5 seconds after connecting, but using other command outside of the project is always annoying and makes irregular.

I found followRedirects options but I don't get how to get the result content and final url if it is taken several seconds.

Is there any packages in Meteor or Node for this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How is the other page doing the redirection? Because the fastest solution would be to parse the HTML you get back from the `HTTP.get`, pull out the URL of the page it’s about to redirect to, and then initiate your own `HTTP.get` request for that new URL. You would likely get the second page in less than 5 seconds.

If the redirect is caused by a `<meta http-equiv="refresh"`, finding the new URL should be straightforward. If it’s initiated by JavaScript, it all depends on the implementation. It could be easy (`<body onload="location.href=...`) or it could be incomprehensible.

As for packages, take a look at [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). This will just help you parse the page, though. If you need to execute JavaScript on the page as part of parsing it (i.e. if it’s not obvious where the redirect is, or it isn’t consistent) you’ll need to call PhantomJS, which you load via NPM. See the examples [here](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-phantomjs).

Comment: The redirection is caused by DDOS attack of the site, so I think it's not happened by <meta http-equiv="refresh"> tag, but would be the JavaScript. (I can't figure it out for now, because they redirect the page when the DDOS occurred)

Comment: BTW, thanks for your answer and I'll ask again when I could figure it out how they redirect their page- thanks.